# Not able to commit to SVN through Jenkins while creating new branch

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am not able to commit to SVN [ver: 1.8.3 (r1516576)], while creating new branch using Jenkins(Jenkins ver. 1.607). SVN Merge plugin(for Jenkins) is on version 2.5. I also installed SVN client[ver: 1.8.11 (r1643975)] on my linux(CentOS 6.6) machine(Where Jenkins is deployed). While creating new branch using "Feature Branches", I got following error:

```
Error

svn: E165001: Commit failed (details follow): svn: E165001: Commit blocked by start-commit hook (exit code 1) with output: Subversion 1.8 or greater is required to commit to this repository. svn: E175002: MKACTIVITY of '/svn/mainframe/!svn/act/e73af38c-4c01-0010-baae-91ffb01757b0': 500 Internal Server Error (https://peri.mojaair.com)

org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E165001: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E165001: Commit blocked by start-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
Subversion 1.8 or greater is required to commit to this repository.
svn: E175002: MKACTIVITY of '/svn/mainframe/!svn/act/e73af38c-4c01-0010-baae-91ffb01757b0': 500 Internal Server Error (https://peri.mojaair.com)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNCopyDriver.copyReposToRepos(SVNCopyDriver.java:378)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNCopyDriver.setupCopy(SVNCopyDriver.java:627)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNCopyClient16.doCopy(SVNCopyClient16.java:440)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnNgReposToReposCopy.run(SvnNgReposToReposCopy.java:65)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnNgReposToReposCopy.run(SvnNgReposToReposCopy.java:23)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1259)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnRemoteCopy.run(SvnRemoteCopy.java:227)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNCopyClient.doCopy(SVNCopyClient.java:581)
    at jenkins.plugins.svnmerge.IntegratableProjectAction.createSVNCopy(IntegratableProjectAction.java:260)
    at jenkins.plugins.svnmerge.IntegratableProjectAction.doNewBranch(IntegratableProjectAction.java:208)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:46)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InterceptedFunction.invoke(Function.java:399)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$13.dispatch(MetaClass.java:411)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:123)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:934)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:515)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1010)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:640)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1618)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1576)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Please let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using an older version of the SVN plugin that is based on the SVN 1.6 protocol, and the administrator of the repository has blocked write access for older clients. Upgrade he SVN plugin to version 2.5

Comment: I my question I have already mentioned that SVN plugin is on version 2.5

Comment: Both the svn and the svn merge plugin? Are you sure?

Comment: Following are version list of the tools:
Jenkins:1.607
    svnmerge:2.5
    subversion:1.8.11

The subversion repository in which I am trying to commit is on version: 1.8.3

Comment: Jenkins has a subversion plugin. This is not the same as the svn that you use on the command line, but a plugin, and you need version 2.5 for SVN 1.8 support. This plugin is included with Jenkins, but Jenkins 1.607 might not include the latest version, so you might have to upgrade it yourself.

Comment: I have checked thoroughly.  Subversion plugin is on version 2.5. I have downloaded from https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin   and installed on Jenkins. But still facing same issue. I think subversion is not sending "txn-client-compat-version" to SVN repository.

Comment: Latest https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/1.608/jenkins.war link is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The Jenkins SVN plugin ver 2.5 does have some issues or at least its not compatible with other Jenkins SVN plugins for now.  Apparently I have found even the latest SVN tagging plugin does not work well alongside it and has code changes pending to accomodate the update.  You may have to revert back to SVN plugin 2.4.5 (you'll still be able to use SVN 1.8 client btw) or conduct the checkout and merge at the command line using a shell task.  Perhaps a previous log will have exposed command line format in order to mimic the plugin.  Either way, you may need to wait for a code fix.